# what is cake sql in cake controller php

Tags: cakephp

I need cake sql in cake controller php file

```
SELECT Time(NOW()),
       evaluation_start_time,
       AddTime(evaluation_start_time, CONCAT(evaluation_hour_after, ':00:00')) temp_start_time,
       AddTime(evaluation_start_time, CONCAT(evaluation_hour_after, ':14:00')) temp_end_time,

  (SELECT count(id)
   FROM evaluation_user_ratings
   WHERE evaluation_id = evaluation.id) player_rating_given,

  (SELECT count(id)
   FROM evaluations_users_and_team
   WHERE evalution_id = evaluation.id) player_count,

  (SELECT rating_added_by
   FROM evaluation_user_ratings
   WHERE evaluation_id = evaluation.id) AS puser_id,
       evaluation.*
FROM evaluation
WHERE evaluation_date >= date(NOW())
  AND (evaluation_day_after != 0
       OR evaluation_hour_after != 0)
  AND evaluation_status = '1'
HAVING player_count >= player_rating_given
AND Time(NOW()) >= temp_start_time
AND Time(NOW()) <= temp_end_time
```

Comment: Which version of cakephp

Comment: What are your associations from EvaluationsTable to EvaluationUserRatingsTable and EvaluationsUsersAndTeamTable?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your query right with a possible typo for column player_count (evalution_id) ..;
For Cakephp 4.0 you have two options which is to use the queryBuilder or the
Connection Manager

The easy one for raw sql is the Connection Manager which you will have to call the Lib beforehand in the Controller and or Parent controller

1.

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
```

2. In your Controller's function, something around the lines below while keeping Cakephp's Table/Entity Naming Structure.

as shown basically

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$query = "SELECT 
                Time(NOW()),
                Evaluation.evaluation_start_time,
                AddTime(Evaluation.evaluation_start_time, CONCAT(Evaluation.evaluation_hour_after, ':00:00')) temp_start_time,
                AddTime(Evaluation.evaluation_start_time, CONCAT(Evaluation.evaluation_hour_after, ':14:00')) temp_end_time,
                (SELECT count(EvaluationUserRatings.id) FROM evaluation_user_ratings EvaluationUserRatings WHERE EvaluationUserRatings.evaluation_id = Evaluation.id) player_rating_given,
                (SELECT count(EvaluationsUsersAndTeam.id) FROM evaluations_users_and_team EvaluationsUsersAndTeam WHERE EvaluationsUsersAndTeam.evaluation_id = Evaluation.id) player_count,
                (SELECT EvaluationUserRatings.rating_added_by FROM evaluation_user_ratings EvaluationUserRatings WHERE  EvaluationUserRatings.evaluation_id = Evaluation.id) AS puser_id,
                Evaluation.*
            FROM evaluation Evaluation
            WHERE Evaluation.evaluation_date >= date(NOW())
              AND (Evaluation.evaluation_day_after != 0
                   OR Evaluation.evaluation_hour_after != 0)
              AND Evaluation.evaluation_status = '1'
            HAVING player_count >= player_rating_given
            AND Time(NOW()) >= temp_start_time
            AND Time(NOW()) <= temp_end_time";

        $results = $connection->execute($query)->fetchAll('assoc');
```

If you decide to use the queryBuilder, I believe this a close representation and or example to get you close to your goal.

```
$evaluations = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Evaluation');
    $queryA = $evaluations->find()
        ->selectAllExcept($evaluations,['Evaluation.evaluation_state_time']);
    $evaltest = $queryA
        ->select([
            'time_now'=>'Time(NOW())',
            'Evaluation.evaluation_start_time',
            'temp_start_time'=>'AddTime(Evaluation.evaluation_start_time, CONCAT(Evaluation.evaluation_hour_after, \':00:00\'))',
            'temp_end_time'=>'AddTime(Evaluation.evaluation_start_time, CONCAT(Evaluation.evaluation_hour_after, \':14:00\'))'
            ])
        
        ->select([
            'player_rating_given'=>$evaluations->EvaluationUserRatings->find()
                    ->join([
                        'Evaluation'=>[
                            'table'=>'evaluation',
                            'conditions'=>'EvaluationUserRatings.evaluation_id = Evaluation.id'
                            ]
                        ])
                    ->count(),
            'player_count'=>$evaluations->EvaluationsUsersAndTeam->find()
                    ->join([
                        'Evaluation'=>[
                            'table'=>'evaluation',
                            'conditions'=>'EvaluationsUsersAndTeam.evaluation_id = Evaluation.id'
                            ]
                        ])
                    ->count(),
            'puser_id'=>$evaluations->EvaluationUserRatings->find()
                    ->select(['EvaluationUserRatings.rating_added_by'])
                    ->join([
                        'Evaluation'=>[
                            'table'=>'evaluation',
                            'conditions'=>'EvaluationUserRatings.evaluation_id = Evaluation.id'
                            ]
                        ])->disableHydration()->toArray()[0]['rating_added_by']
            ])
        ->where([
            'Evaluation.evaluation_date >= date(NOW())',
            'Evaluation.evaluation_status = "1"',
            'OR'=>[
                'Evaluation.evaluation_day_after != 0',
                'Evaluation.evaluation_hour_after != 0'
                ]
            ])
        ->having([
            'player_count >= player_rating_given',
            'Time(NOW()) >= Time(temp_start_time)',
            'Time(NOW()) <= Time(temp_end_time)'
            ]);
    print_r($evaltest->disableHydration()->toArray());
```

This will return an object which you can simply turn into an array by adding **->toArray();** to the end of the queryBuilder above.

results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [evaluation_date] => 2023-11-25 06:09:00
            [evaluation_day_after] => 1
            [evaluation_hour_after] => 0
            [evaluation_status] => 1
            [evaluation_start_time] => 06:08:00
            [time_now] => 06:11:02
            [temp_start_time] => 06:08:00.000000
            [temp_end_time] => 06:22:00.000000
            [player_rating_given] => 1
            [player_count] => 1
            [puser_id] => 3
        )

)
```

After some local testing I noticed some things that might come in handy.

1. In the model which cake using frozen Date time might be an issue, so to combat this in the EvaluationTable.php add to your public function initialize. If your have any other DateTime columns I would do the same to those as well.

   $this->getSchema()->setColumnType('evaluation_date', 'string');

In your config/app.php make sure your defaultTimeZone is accurate as well as your system's / server's time.

Im taking a shot in the dark on the model but my testing model is as follows for primary table evaluation:

```
TABLE `evaluation` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `evaluation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluation_day_after` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluation_hour_after` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluation_status` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluation_start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Hope that helps. Good luck. Oh one more thing about the queryBuilder, the * wildcard I believe it not allowed that is the reason for the prep-query function **->selectAllExcept()** as a workaround.

Comment: It is not runing, boss

Comment: so Im assuming your using version Cakephp 4, and in your src->Model->Tables->Evaluation.php file, you have the 2 tables: EvaluationUserRatings and EvaluationsUsersAndTeam in hasMany or hasOne type associations ? and which path did you choose?